# Ubuntu install complete restart your pc... begins installation from the start

Tags: software-installation

So the installation of Ubuntu is finished and it tells me that the pc has to be restarted. After it's restarted I get the same screen as I got the first time using the bootable USB.

I get the option to try Ubuntu without installing it, install Ubuntu, OEM install (for manufactures) and check disc for defects.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGrc3.jpg

I've been through it twice without success. Choosing install Ubuntu begins the install again and ends with the restart that begins the cycle again.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or not?

Comment: Did you remove the USB?

Comment: I did not. Do I have to?

Comment: Yes you have to remove the USB drive.

Comment: ...else you are simply booting from the USB *again*.

Comment: It never tells me to take it out. Looked it up on Youtube and it doesn't do that for me. It gives me the option the restart and when I press that I get this screen: http://imgur.com/a/jRQCBdS and after that it immeaditly reboots.

Comment: Whether it tells you to or not, you need to remove it.

Comment: I tried that. At various points. All leads to no bootable device.

Comment: You likely installed grub on the USB instead of on your pc. Redo the install and install grub on the drive your pc should boot from.

Comment: Do I need to remake the bootable usb for this?

Comment: To avoid any issues, you'd better remake the bootable USB since it is possible that you installed grub on it. And when you're asked to choose the drive where to install Ubuntu, make sure you choose your hard drive not your USB drive.

Comment: Alright. It worked, I think. I haven't restarted my laptop yet, but I'm in Ubuntu without the USB now. The restart went the same as usual, but I clicked f12 and it only showed me the USB as boot option. Pulled the USB out and it gave me an error, but it loaded up Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

After the installation process is finished, you will be asked to remove the USB drive that you used to install Ubuntu then restart your PC.
All what you have to do is to unplug the USB drive then restart your computer so that it will be able to start Ubuntu.

**EDIT:**
After the install is completed, you should enter the BIOS menu (when you start your PC) and change the boot order, so that your PC boots to its hard drive instead the USB drive.

Comment: Never saw it ask me to take it out and I was glued to the screen. I looked it up on Youtube and what I saw certainly did not happen. This is all it shows me after I press restart and then it immediately boots itself: http://imgur.com/a/jRQCBdS.  Am I supposed to just wing it and pull it out when it's about the shutdown or what am I doing wrong here? I'm sorry if I'm being stupid, but I just don't see it.

Comment: Let's start from the beginning, how does the installation process end?

Comment: It says the installation has been completed and the pc needs to be restarted. When I press restart it shows me the screen I posted above and after that it reboots itself and brings me back to the beginning. I see on YouTube that people get the text to remove the usb and reboot, but I just got those 4 lines and then automatic reboot.

Comment: May be there is something wrong.
And what happens when remove the USB drive then reboot your PC?

Comment: If I remove the usb and then click restart I get a screen with a lot of text and then it actually does tell me to put the usb out and press enter. However at that point the usb is already out and enter does not work; putting the usb back in and out doesn't change anything either. Pressing the power button to shut of and restart the laptop tells me there is no bootable device. Shutting the laptop of when given the option to restart gives me those 4 lines from earlier and then it shuts down, i taken out the usb and same issue: no bootable device.

Comment: I think you should change the boot order so that your PC will boot to the hard drive instead the USB drive. You can do this from the BIOS menu.

Comment: After the install, shut the computer down completely. Then remove the USB and power it on.  This is the simplest way.

Comment: Organic Marble, I've done that a couple times without success. It always leads to no bootable device. I've now changed the boot order but so far getting the same result.

Comment: The reason for removing usb drive is to make sure that the computer boots from the hard disk not the flash drive. So if the installation completed successfully make sure you are booting from the hard disk. You can manually boot from hdd there's a key depending on your bios that displays a list of devices you can boot from and you can choose your hard disk. And considering boot order are you sure you saved the changes?

Comment: So, after reinstalling the USB twice I got it to work. It's a bit messy, but it work. When I boot my laptop without the USB it gives me the "no bootable device", but when I boot it with the USB, press F12 for the boot menu, take out the USB; get an error, press enter and suddenly a can select to boot with an " unknown source". Which brings me straight to Ubuntu. I have installed my own programs and made changes etc, everything gets saved. So I have no clue why it works like it does, but for now I'm fine with it.

Comment: Glad you finally got it work.